# Google Maps API Dropdown Change Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've referred to [How do you style the dropdown on Google Places Autocomplete API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893857/how-do-you-style-the-dropdown-on-google-places-autocomplete-api), and could't find the answer to my problem. I changed the .pac-item class on hover, focus and active but didn't work. Before I upload the pictures, let me tell you the problem. There's a dropdown, which is a google autofill feature. I want the background color of the list items to be #0085c6 (class - blue) when I go over an option. Now, this works fine when I hover on it (as seen on the pic), however, when I use the arrow keys to traverse through the list the background color becomes #ff5a5f (class - red).

Please, help! Thanks.

Works fine on hover, i.e.,

```
   .pac-item:hover{
      color: white !important;
      background-color: #0085c6 !important;
    }
```

[image]

But, when arrow keys are used: 
[image]

Comment: Could you check if this RED color is from some css? If yes you can directly change that css file.

Comment: I tried searching the entire directory with the color code, zero results. Since you suggested, I'll do it again.

Comment: Arrow keypress event should be bind to a function adding a class to current element or change it directly through js.

Comment: roomtitan.com - this is the site. The problem I am talking about is in the homepage itself. Please have a look.

Comment: It's adding a class called `pac-item-selected` and color is from one of your css file. Just change ALL background-color of this class. It'll work.

Comment: If you don't want to change all of this class. You can add that class directly in the element and check which css is actually referring to using dev-tool.